CSS - How to make linear-gradient more uniform when there is offset

It's evident that solid demarkation of yellow is not properly faded
How to make it decently fade when I add an offset?
html::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid yellow;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, yellow 40%, transparent) 120;
}


why are you using border-image? define a height and use background instead. It's better

It’s not so evident to me that it’s not properly faded. What effect did you want?

Theory
People are good at detecting visual changes. We can detect changes not just from one color to another, but also from one rate of change to another. To compensate, you have to slow down the rate of change.
Of course the linear-gradient function can only approximate a changing rate of change, so a little experimentation will be required for how many steps are necessary to look smooth across that distance. Giving yourself more distance over which to make the change can also help distribute the changes better. (That might mean lowering the 40% barrier, or increasing the border width, or both.)
Mechanics
If you use a dimension value (e.g. 20% or 2rem) without a color value, the linear-gradient CSS function assumes the color value is 50% of the way between the two color stops around it.
In the example below, I use more than 60% of the width to perform the transition, and spend more of the distance transitioning between solid and halfway than I do between halfway and transparent.
Example
html::before {

    /* ... */

    --solid-at: 20%;
    --transparent-at: 100%;
    --speedup: 135%;
    
    --diff: calc( var(--transparent-at) - var(--solid-at) );
    --mid-diff: calc( var(--diff) * 0.5 );
    --adjusted-mid: calc( var(--mid-diff) * var(--speedup) );
    --new-stop: calc( var(--solid-at) + var(--adjusted-mid) );

    border-image: 
        linear-gradient( to bottom, 
            yellow var(--solid-at), 
            var(--new-stop),
            transparent var(--transparent-at)
        ) 120;
}

This equates to solid yellow at 20%, half-transparent at 74% (instead of 60%), and fully transparent at 100%.
Tools
Unlike many CSS gradient tools, colorgradient.dev lets you model this behavior by removing a color value from a stop.
